# Why data plans of companies are required to surf internet?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have searched a lot about, what the title says. I didn't get the exact answer what i wanted to know. My question is simple. Why data plans are required to surf through internet? Do they have any special access to the internet or it's just a distance which matters a lot in communication between server and client?

Comment: You want internet access, you pay company who supplies that service, or spend your days in Starbucks. Simples.

Comment: No. I am asking it in a technical context. Do they have any special access to the internet services or they just act as medium between website and client because of distance. Or there is any other reason?

Comment: Somebody, somewhere, has to pay a company to supply a service - that's what companies do, they make money or they go bust. What exactly is it you don't understand about that?

Comment: Because the Internet is nothing but Data, and that is where their cost is.

Answer (score 1):

> Why are data plans required to surf the internet?

The internet is simply a [large collection of computer networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_backbone). So, in short, the reason someone typically needs to pay a fee for a "data plan" to access the internet is because:

- Maintaining a given network isn't free.
- Sometimes the separate companies that make up the internet charge each other fees to [pass data between networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interconnect_agreement).

> I am asking in a technical context.

There is no technical reason you need a "data plan". Theoretically, assuming the company you obtained internet access through decided those services would be free, they could be free.